# Getting INVALID_TAB_OPERATION when trying to delete or modify "Restrict Changes" Tabs in drafted Envelopes since v2.1

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

We've been developing a web application which uses DocuSign's API for around a year now and it was just updated to version 2.1, which seems to have caused an issue with our application. One use case for our application, which is now unable to work, is as follows:

A document has errors and needs to be sent back to our representatives and clients while maintaining information that was already filled in to be re-signed, but the simple cloning of an envelope removes all information filled in.

In order to circumvent this problem and get our application functioning as intended, we do the following:

1. Get a list of all of the tabs on the envelope
2. Clone the envelope as a draft (status: 'created')
3. Delete all of the tabs off of the newly cloned envelope
4. Making modifications such as removing any signatures from signature boxes
5. Add all of the tabs to the cloned envelope
6. Send the envelope

This all worked until around the end of last week (v2.1 of the API releasing on 08/02) when we realized that tabs were starting to be duplicated. After some investigation, we noticed that the tabs being duplicated were set to be "Restrict Changes" and were not being deleted by our API calls which used to override that sender permission. Since then, we've tried simply updating the cloned tabs with a PUT request after adding a value to certain tabs, which also gives us an INVALID_TAB_OPERATION error. While we haven't seen any documentation in the v2.1 update to suggest that change, we believe it has happened, whether it be a feature or a bug.

So the question is: was this change intended and can it be circumvented somehow to get our application functioning? If it was an intended change, can admins have an option to allow API calls to override these types of lock outs?

Comment: If you switch back to v2 does it still work?
When you delete the tabs, do you receive an error response from the API call?

Comment: On both v2.1 and v2, the API call goes through and returns a 200 status, no errors.

Comment: So you feel that the specific issue is that the delete tabs API method call shows a success status but is not actually deleting the tab? Please use [API Logging](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging) to pull out the request/response for the method and update your question with the log (XXX out your account id)

Comment: While we are getting a 200, all tabs (all having the Mandatory and Restrict Changes flags as true) return an INVALID_TAB_OPERATION error. This was not the case prior to the API update. I would understand the locking of tabs had the envelope been sent, but it's still a draft at the time of these API calls, so I don't know why they can't be changed.

Comment: Ok, we're getting closer. Please update (edit) your question to focus on the real issue: You used to be able to delete tabs in a draft envelope, now you're receiving INVALID_TAB_OPERATION for the request. (Is this the best description of the issue?)

Comment: The topic was updated as was some of the information

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this was an intended change to the API as deleting and modifying restricted tabs in the v2 API was seen as a bug.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Did you learn this from DocuSign Customer Service? I have filed documentation issue DEVDOCS-1354 to have the change added to the changes page for v2.1

Comment: I confirmed this with a member of the development team directly.